# calendar picker can't be hidden on firefox browser

Tags: html, css, date, input

I'm trying to hide the calendar picker of input type="date and it's not working on firefox.

while it's working fine with `input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{ display: none;}` in chrome browser, it seems that firefox doesnt support that !

Comment: Looks like this worked in FF < 109, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1812397, but has been changed after that. Don't know if there is currently any working replacement.